# Ideas for making money off a website

Tags: resources, idea, revenue, monetize

I'm considering acquiring a website that traffics close to 20k a month. It's currently unprofitable, but obviously I would need to change that to justify the cost.

It's a support site for a framework similar to CakePHP. A resource that allows people to find plugins for that site. How would you go about expanding this site so that it would be broad enough to raise traffic and how would you make money off of it?

Some ideas I've had:
1- BuySellAds.com seem to make ads classy and relevant
2- Team up with other sites in some way (What ways? ... Ecommerce sites that sell plugins (like CodeCanyon), etc)
3- Write tutorials and such to drive more traffic (time consuming, and already heavily saturated for this framework).

Are there resources out there that help webmasters in ways like this?

Comment: Also, let me know of any sites that may be doing something like this already that are doing it well.

Answer (score 1):

Websites that are targeted towards developers/programmers tend to have very low click thru rates for advertisements.

You may want to consider selling listings for developers to advertise their services particularly for that framework. You could also sell space for job listings or for developers looking to be hired.

Content drives traffic so more tutorials would be a huge plus as they are always popular (assuming they are well done). You may want to consider allowing users to submit tutorials in exchange for a free link to their website. That way you get lots of free content (only add tutorials that don't suck) and they get a link that has some value (SEO and driving traffic).

Comment: John, you might want to check this blog post (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/state-of-the-stack-2010-a-message-from-your-ceo/).

Answer (score 1):

Howabout an App Store type model? You provide all the facilities for developers to sell their plugins online, where you take a cut of the transaction.

Since developers are your likely audience, think about the types of companies who would want to market to developers. Perhaps you could partner with software companies offering commercial IDE software, or conferences (where again you take a cut of referrals).

Comment: I have thought about this type of ecommerce site... I would be interested in digging deeper into it. I wonder what legal things I would have to get in order to do something like that. Thanks for the suggestion!